# Override app/config/parameters.yml in multiple bundles on Symfony2

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

I have multiple sub-bundles and a main one, the core bundle.

The core bundle has a `config.yml` file and a `parameters.yml` file.
I want the `app/config/config.yml` to use the overriding of the `parameters.yml` file from each sub-bundle.

For exemple, here's a code for `app/config/parameters.yml` file :

```
parameters:
    database_name: core_db
```

Here's a code for `app/config/config.yml` file :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
```

Here's a code for one of the sub-bundle `parameters.yml` file :

```
parameters:
    database_name: sub_db
```

I want that the database_name used is `sub_db` (and `xx_db` for the other sub-bundle, etc) but don't know how to do that and if it's possible.

Comment: You will need to clarify (to yourself) what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  There can be only one default connection.  You can create a different connection for each bundle but that is a different concept.  And parameter.yml was designed for secure application (not bundle) specific parameters.  Makes little sense to have bundle specific copies.  Might want to take a look at the configuration section in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of understanding, the database_name option was just an example. I'm not trying to have several connections. I could have written other parameters like `phone: 0 000 000 000` from my parameters.yml file. Here I want to override app/config/parameters.yml with, for example, src/Project/MyBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml

Comment: Abstract questions are not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Perhaps you could explain why you want to override a phone number?

Comment: Ok, here are better explainations. I have 3 bundles which are 3 different websites using the same Core Bundle. The parameters' values are different for each of the 3 bundles. Now, the config.yml file uses the values of the app/config/parameters.yml file. The config.yml file should use the parameters.yml of each sub bundle. For example, the payment system or Swift Mailer use different logins for each sub bundle.

Comment: Three different websites imply three different app directories and thus three different sets of config files.  Still don't see the issue.

Comment: I already tried to override the 3 different config.yml sub bundles' files by creating an extension file and using prepend inside it (I don't create 3 different apps because all of those 3 sub bundles use the Core Bundle)